# How can I update xml data in clob data type field using simple translate function?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, sql-update, clob

How can I update XML data in clob data type using simple translate function in SQL Developer.

To show table:

```sql
Select * from AmanTest;
```

To update field:

```sql
Update AmanTest Set fULLName = 'Aman 1991'; commit;
```

To replace characters (masking):

```sql
Update AmanTest Set fULLName = Translate(FullName,'amnA19','artA50'); commit;
```

Run The Query

```
Output- 'Arat 5005'
```

Problem statement: I want update data in XML like:

```xml
<oip:process xmlns:oip="http://xyz.com.au/GoldSendEmail/OIPSendEmailService">
   <oip:fromEmailAddress>amanclaims@btfinancialgroup.com</oip:fromEmailAddress>
   <oip:toEmailAddress>WBCTest06@btfin-dev.com</oip:toEmailAddress>
   <oip:ccEmailAddress />
   <oip:emailSubject>SCI premium waiver - 111179657</oip:emailSubject>
   <oip:emailBody>
       Member Number: 111179657 
       Claim Number: CLM-55 
       Member Name: Aman Usrete
       Thank you,
       Health Claims Team
   </oip:emailBody>
```

Specifically, I want to update email address and member name.

Answer (score 0):

If your XML data is stored in a CLOB, you can do the following:

```sql
UPDATE AmanTest att
SET att.xml_col = 
  XMLSERIALIZE(CONTENT 
               UPDATEXML(XMLTYPE(att.xml_col), 
                         '/Process/toEmailAddress/text()', 
                         'TO@EMAIL.COM',
                         '/Process/emailBody/text()',                         
                   REGEXP_REPLACE(EXTRACTVALUE(XMLTYPE(at.xml_col),
                                               '/Process/emailBody/text()'), 
                                  'Member Name:\s\w+\s\w+', 
                                  'Member Name: New MemberName')) 
               AS CLOB INDENT);
```

Comment: Thanks Del.
When I running this query ,I am getting below error-
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "FE"."EXPRESSION_STATEMENT": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: @amanusrete Oops.  fe.expression_statement is a column from one of my databases.  I was testing the query out before I posted it and missed removing that reference.  I've edited the response now.